# Get installed app's icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageicon, url-scheme

Is it possible to get the icon file of an app (on NOT-jailbroken devices)?
Could URL schemes be used to do this? Is there an API to get the icon or the only way to obtain the image is by downloading it from iTunes?

Comment: Please clarify. Where do you wish to get the icon from? If from an iOS app running on the device, are you trying to get the app's own icon or the icons of other apps?

Comment: I would like to get the icons from all the installed apps

Comment: Get them from where? Please don't make this a game of 20 questions. Update your question to be clear about what you are trying do. Then update your question with what you've tried or what you have researched.

Comment: No, this is not possible. If you want the icon really bad, I'd suggest just scraping the iTunes preview webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS apps run in Sandbox mode, which means that you can't access it's information, including icons.
If you need icons, you may get it from iTunes preview page, but you will face many other problems to get it done as, for example, how you will get the list of installed apps and it's id's on iTunes.